# How can I trigger RACSignal combine latest with update to NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I am new to Reactive Cocoa and having trouble understanding it. But here is how I am using RACObserve & RACSignal. In my viewDidLoad:

```
 [[RACSignal combineLatest:@[RACObserve(self, cellArray)]] subscribeNext:^(id x) { 
// I've set a breakpoint here.
 }];
```

I want to trigger the above code/block when I update cellArray (NSMutableArray). I'm getting data via an API and adding the data to my cellArray like this:

```
[self.cellArray insertObject:item atIndex:x];
```

Or

```
[self.cellArray addObject:item];
```

Am I implementing this properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can't observe insertions/deletions in an array like that. This has been discussed extensively before. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1197#issuecomment-38492480) solution in RAC's repo. Basically in your case would like:

```
NSMutableArray *contents = [self mutableArrayValueForKey:"cellArray"];
[contents addObject: item];
```